# Route doesn't match in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm learning about react so I'm developing a personal blog with it. Moreover I use react-route but I've a problem because  I don't understand why a route doesn't render (the route: /articule/:id). You can see the code in [repository](https://github.com/pasteles/blog).

In the index.js  define the route:

```
//it  works
//index.js
const app = (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={IRMBlog} />
      <Route path="/articule/:id"  component={IRMArticule}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

But If I move the line `<Route path="/articule/:id"  component={IRMArticule}/>` to other file It doesn't work, why?

The file when I move the line of code is `irm-articule-list.js`

```
render() {
return (
  <div className="column is-10 is-offset-1">
    <IRMArticuleBox></IRMArticuleBox>
    <IRMArticuleBox></IRMArticuleBox>
    <Route path="/articule/:id"  component={IRMArticule}/>
  </div>
);
```

}

In the file `irm-articule-box.js`, I've  `<Link to="/articule/001">`

Comment: which file you are trying to move it? paste the code please?

Comment: Please provide to which you want to move it to?

Comment: in other file if you have articule id then you need to use <Link> tag.I'm answering this question show there.

Comment: I move `<Route path="/articule/:id"  component={IRMArticule}/>` to `irm-articule-list.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Because application must have only one router, and router in react it's almost root component, one input for matching your urls

Comment: I've only one Router in `ìndex.js`

Answer (score 0):

Like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react;
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class articuleDetails extends Component {
 render(){

   return (
   .....
    <Link to="/articule/123"> articule name</Link>
   ...
   )    

 }
}
```

Comment: I've a Link in `articule-list-box`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to move it? 
In general you should know that Route must be inside a Router, and its job is to tell the browser which component to render when its path matches the location. It is not a hyperlink like the tag  in HTML.
If your intention was hyperlink you should use `<Link to="/">`

Comment: But  the component `IRMArticuleList`  is inside the component `IRMBlog ` which is used in a Route component

Comment: You are correct, but It needs to be directly inside the router component. As in the [docs example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start). If you want to deeply understand the reason for it, I suggest you to explore the library repository, and specifically [Route](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js)

Comment: But inside nested routing you can see that  Route isn't inside Router.